# FFMPEG doesn't decode the first few frames with multithreaded decoding. C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

So to get better decoding speeds, I'm setting

```
av_stream->codec->thread_count = 32;
av_stream->codec->thread_type = FF_THREAD_FRAME;
```

This greatly improves decoding time, but seems to lose some frames (equaling the amount of threads I set)

For the first 32 or so frames, av_readframe(), and avcodec_send_packet() succeed, but avcodec_recieve_frame() seems to fail.

This seems to result in the last 31 frames to not be decoded, as my loop exits once avcodec_send_packet() fails.

Anyone know how I can get the final frames to also be decoded? I read something about flushing the buffers, but I'm not really sure how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: There's not even close enough to enough information here to provide an answer. You could start with a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You should provide the reproducible source code. Without any info, nobody can help you.